# Please update your Git remote warning despite correct remote origin?

Tags: git

Sometimes when I push something to my repository, I get a warning that I should change my git remote:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 538 bytes | 538.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Project 'memberportal/framework' was moved to 'memberportal/memberportal'.
remote: 
remote: Please update your Git remote:
remote: 
remote:   git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:memberportal/memberportal.git
remote: 
remote: 
To gitlab.com:memberportal/memberportal.git
   5029948f..570e2f52  master -> master
```

Its true that I moved  'memberportal/framework' to 'memberportal/memberportal' a very long time ago. But I already changed my origin. The command `git remote -v` gives me

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:memberportal/memberportal.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:memberportal/memberportal.git (push)
```

But I still get the warning from time to time. How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably can't. The lines prefixed with `remote:` are not coming from your Git software, and are not coming from the Git software on GitLab. They're coming from some add-on software that the Git on GitLab runs. That add-on software spits out this message—who knows why; that's up to it—and the GitLab Git relays it to your Git, which relays it to you with `remote:` in front. You would have to get this add-on software fixed. If it's not under your control, there may be nothing you can do.

Comment: I imagine that whoever put it in thought: *Let's just emit this message every time* or *Let's just emit this message 50% of the time* or something along those lines. Think of it like the reminder to set your clock back or forward for the DST shift twice a year. They have no idea whether you have done this already, they just keep telling you.

Comment: @torek  if I remove my local git repository and clone it again, will I still receive this message?

Comment: Probably. I have no idea whether they're using any sort of test, in whatever code emits this message, and if they *are* using some sort of test, I have no idea what it might be. But it's hard to imagine they have a good test that will work if you re-clone, but doesn't work now.